# I want to view news RSS 10 by 10

Tags: php

This code extracts a json file from a certain news site rss and prints them all, but the page opens late because too many news are printed at the same time. When you scroll down to the bottom after 10 news, it would be great if you show the other 10 news as well. I tried many things and couldn't. Is there anyone who can do this for me?

```php
    <?php
    $page_title = 'Gündem Haberleri &amp; Son Dakika Haberleri';
    
    $rss_urls = array(
        'https://www.cnnturk.com/feed/rss/all/news',
        'https://webrazzi.com/feed',
    );
    
    $combined_data = array();
    
    foreach ($rss_urls as $rss_url) {
        $rss = simplexml_load_file($rss_url);
    
        if ($rss) {
            foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
                $channel_title = (string)$rss->channel->title;
                $title = (string)$item->title;
                $link = (string)$item->link;
                $description = (string)$item->description;
                $pubDate = (string)$item->pubDate;
                $images = (string)$item->image;
                $image = '';
                $evrim = '';
                $thumbnail = (string)$item->thumbnail['url'];
    
                $media_content = $item->children('media', true)->content;
                if ($media_content) {
                    foreach ($media_content as $content) {
                        $attributes = $content->attributes();
                        if ($attributes['medium'] == 'image') {
                            $image = (string)$attributes['url'];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                $media_content = $item->children('media', true)->content;
                if ($media_content) {
                    foreach ($media_content as $content) {
                        $url = $content->attributes()->url;
                        if ($url) {
                            $evrim = (string)$url;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                $item_data = array(
                    'Kanal Başlığı' => $channel_title,
                    'Başlık' => $title,
                    'Bağlantı' => $link,
                    'Açıklama' => $description,
                    'Yayın Tarihi' => $pubDate,
                    'Resim' => $image,
                    'Resimm' => $images,
                    'Evrim' => $evrim,
                    'Thumbnail' => $thumbnail
                );
    
                $combined_data[] = $item_data;
            }
        } else {
            echo "RSS beslemesi yüklenemedi: $rss_url<br>";
        }
    }
    
    shuffle($combined_data);
    
    $search_results = array();
    if (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])) {
        $search_query = $_GET['search'];
        foreach ($combined_data as $item) {
            if (stripos($item['Başlık'], $search_query) !== false || stripos($item['Açıklama'], $search_query) !== false) {
                $search_results[] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="width: 100%; max-width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto">
            <div class="content">
            <?php foreach ($combined_data as $item): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $item['Bağlantı']; ?>" target="_blank"><div class="card">
                    <div class="ns">
                        <img src="<?php echo $item['Resimm'] . $item['Evrim'] . $item['Thumbnail']; ?>">
                        <div class="details">
                            <p class="kaynak"><?php echo $item['Kanal Başlığı']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="baslik"><?php echo $item['Başlık']; ?></h1>
                    </div>
                </div></a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I couldn't find many resources related to RSS, I searched everywhere but there is none. I tried to try something with ajax but it didn't work. It would be better for me with something other than ajax.

Comment: You can't implement "infinite scrolling" or otherwise update your page asynchronously without Javascript. If you don't want to use JS to load more, you can always implement regular pagination.